# FB SDK Login working sometimes

Tags: java, android, facebook

I've an app that is in beta phase in which the fb login sometimes doesnt work. It just opens the login dialog and then closes when you click "Confirm" button, leaving you in my app login page.

The thing is, this error happens just to random phones when someone downloads my app from the store; if compiled from my android studio, this error fixes.

It happened in my mom's grand prime until I compiled it from the studio.

It happens in my friends J1 Ace.

It does not happen in my (restored to factory) J1 Ace.

It does not happen in other 4 devices I tested it on.

I cant replicate this error, has someone experienced this issue before?

Comment: Did you export right key hash it has to be release key as your app is on Play Store?

Comment: Yep, I exported the right key. In fact the app works in 80% of the devices it was downloaded on, seems quite odd to me